# Additional Include Directories not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

In Visual Studio C++, I go to the project settings, additional include directories, then add the directory of the file to the list. However, when I try to include the file, it can't find it, I've restarted Visual Studio and that doesn't work.

Here's my include directories:
[A picture of my include directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN7oy.png)

Here's the error I get:
[A picture of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmgH7.png)

Comment: Can you show how you're including the file and the exact error message?

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: Does the include have a path? Perhaps you did not take that into account.

Comment: Are using `""` or `<>` when including?

Comment: Just added the pictures of the errors and stuff

Comment: Does the cocos2d folder have an extensions folder?

Comment: It looks to me like cocos2d assumes you are using cmake to create your project.

Comment: Also it seems your binaries were for Visual Studio 2012 and your IDE appears to be newer.

Comment: Yes, the cocos2d folder does have an extensions folder. Even if cocos2d is assuming that I'm using CMake, still, why doesn't the include directories work. And, my binaries were for Visual Studio 2012, I don't entirely know what that means, can I update it or something?

Comment: Is your compiler Visual Studio 2012? If not you should get proper binaries for your compiler. However this is not the bug.

Comment: Your compiler is telling you that ExtensionMacros.h is not in the Home/cocos2d/extensions folder.

Comment: How do I check my compiler version, because I've never even downloaded Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: ExtensionMacros.h is in the extensions folder, the problem is that the compiler doesn't see extensions as a directory

Comment: Help -> about Visual Studio. Will tell you what version of Visual Studio you are using.

Comment: ***the problem is that the compiler doesn't see extensions as a directory*** That does not make a lot of sense. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Did you set the path for Debug also? From your screenshots it appears it is set for Release. And appears that the Release build succeeds. Remember that each configuration has separate settings.

Comment: I checked the version and everything is 2013, also what I mean is, the compiler isn't able to access the extensions folder, when I type include, nothing inside the extensions folder shows up

Comment: YOU FIXED IT. Yes, that was the problem, I can't believe I screwed up like that.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2012 have binary incompatibilities. It is not generally safe to use the binaries compiled with a different version of Visual Studio (well before VS2015). However that is a different problem from the question.

Answer (score 3):

**The problem was that I was modifying the include directories under the release configuration mode**

Make sure to switch to debug before modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to add your file to the Project:

Go left click on the project and choose "Add"->"ExistingItem"

A simple file browser will open, now you can just pick the desired file and confirm.

Now you need just to `#include "TheNewFile` where you need the new file...

Comment: I can't do that, it's a folder I'm trying to add